# JDBC Connection Error - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have a jar that connects to a DB. The first time I connect to the machine, the jar runs fine, connects to the DB and queries the tables properly etc. However, when I try a second and third time etc, the jar begins to run but gets stuck when connecting to the DB and then I receive the following error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot
>   create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: Connection reset)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)

I checked and there is no problem with the firewall. The strange part is that it works once but then stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database server is accepting connections from the Confluence server TCP address and user is authorized to connect.